# Field placeholder is not displayed react-query-builder

Tags: reactjs, query-builder

I'm using react-query-builder library. But when I add a rule, the place holder label is not displayed.

[image: blue field, no text is shown]

(blue field) no text is shown

I would like to show a label like "Select an option". Here is part of the config JSON, where I add the ***fieldPlaceholder***

```
"fieldLabel": "Field",
"operatorLabel": "Operator",
"funcLabel": "Function",
"fieldPlaceholder": "Select field",
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Could you add the component as well ?

Comment: <Query
        {...config}
        value={internalTree}
        onChange={onChangeQuery}
        renderBuilder={renderBuilder}
      />

just like that?

Answer (score 0):

A placeholder for the field selector is only displayed in the default components if you set `autoSelectField={false}`. [Documentation here](https://react-querybuilder.js.org/docs/components/querybuilder#autoselectfield).

To customize the placeholder text, use the `translations` prop ([docs here](https://react-querybuilder.js.org/docs/components/querybuilder#translations)), like this:

```
<QueryBuilder
  fields={fields}
  query={query}
  onQueryChange={q => setQuery(q)}
  autoSelectField={false}
  translations={{
    fields: {
      placeholderLabel: 'Select a field...',
    },
  }}
/>
```

[Sample CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/20j1oo?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx).

[image: Field selector placeholder]